# How can I upload a file to zookeeper (solr configset synonyms.xml file) using curl / rest API?

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to upload a file into my solr's configset folder stored in zookeeper. I'm hoping to do this from a rather limited serverless function on Azure, which does not have access to Java or the zookeeper command line client. After researching for a bit, it looks like there is no HTTP way to copy a file to zookeeper - is this correct? How can I, if it's possible, upload a file to zookeeper with HTTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body of the request should be a zip file that contains the configset. The zip file must be created from within the conf directory (i.e., `solrconfig.xml` must be the top level entry in the zip file).

Here is an example on how to create the zip file named `"myconfig.zip"` and upload it as a config set named `"myConfigSet"`:

```
$ (cd solr/server/solr/configsets/sample_techproducts_configs/conf && zip -r - *) > myconfigset.zip

$ curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" --data-binary @myconfigset.zip "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/configs?action=UPLOAD&name=myConfigSet"
```

Please refer the [solr Documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/configsets-api.html)